ol​/interaction​/Link: how to read a custom parameter?
Question about OpenLayers ol/interaction/Link:
I would like to set and later use a custom parameter.
The first part went OK:
link.update('ext',  map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()));
This update the map link to http://localhost:5173/onze-percelen/?x=155000&y=463000&z=3&r=0&l=0111111&ext=-169710.40000000002%2C274840%2C479710.4%2C651160
Perfect!
Now I want to use this custom parameter ext, so I need to get it first.
I thought someting like:
    let myExtent = link.get('ext');
    console.log(myExtent);

But all I get is an undefined.
What am I doing wrong/How should I go about?

The example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/link.html?x=0&y=0&z=2.87575&r=0&l=1&example=checked uses a track callback, so link.track('ext', (myExtent) => console.log(myExtent)); should work for you.

Yeah, I did have a look at this Map Link example, but somehow I do not get it running in my code. So, problem persists, unfortunately: I am perfectly able to set the parameter with update, but after that I am not able to get the value back... :-(

This https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jtnenz?file=index.html,package.json,index.js combines a map link with an extent interaction https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-interaction.html and recreates the extent interaction in its previous state when you refresh
